# How i check if a specific number.word exist in a line?

Tags: bash, shell-script

like i have this lines on the file {218394 ted 'y' ted} {131241 john 'n' ted} and i want to check if its y continue if its n dont !

i have this code until now!:

```
read -p "Enter your answer : " 
echo "your answer is: $answer"
if grep -q "$answer" "$sin"
then
    echo "y"
else
    echo "n"
fi
```

what i want is to control if inside 'sin' file in the specific column/line for example $3 its y or n!

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: For structured input, `awk` will be your friend - not `grep`

Answer (score 1):

If the string `Y , N` is always going to be at pos three,then the below should do it for you. If not you will need to build a regex.

```
[devuser@me]$ echo "218394 ted 'y' ted" | awk '{print $3}'
'y'
[devuser@me]$ echo "218394 ted 'n' ted" | awk '{print $3}'
'n'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `cut`:

```
if [[ $(cut -d ' ' -f 3) == 'y' ]]; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```